# UbuntuOne fails with AttributeError on Windows7

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7

I just installed UbuntuOne on a machine at home, but when I tried to connect to my account I got

```
AttributeError "'NoneType' object has no attibute 'get_rootdir'"
```

Every time I start UbuntuOne on that machine, I get that error and it doesn't show any folders.

Answer (score 1):

That error message usually means SyncDaemon is failing to start. So yes, you need to file a bug or a support request.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to [file a bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Bugs)! In the meantime, you can access your docs through a browser at [one.ubuntu.com](http://one.ubuntu.com)